# How to show an element in each div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

My code is:

```
<div id="post">
<a href="./?act=remove&post_id=13" id="remove">Delete</a>
<b>Admin</b> says:
"Hi to all my frends!"
<br>
7 hours ago &middot; 
<a id="like" href="./?act=like&id=13" title="No one likes">Like</a> &middot; 
<a id="dislike" href="./?act=dislike&id=13" title="No one dislikes">Dislike</a>
</div>
```

I also have multiple posts like this one above... How can i make with jQuery that every time I "mouseover" #post, the #remove inside *that* #post appears?

Comment: don't use the same id on multiple elements. What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think you want to use `class="post"` and `class="remove"` if you have multiple posts like that one. Then you can do it like this ([the code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKbCg/3/)):

```
$(".post").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).find(".remove").show();
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).find(".remove").hide();
});
```

Some jQuery functions you might want to look into: [.on()](http://jqapi.com/#p=on), [.mouseover()](http://jqapi.com/#p=mouseover), [.mouseout()](http://jqapi.com/#p=mouseout), [.hover()](http://jqapi.com/#p=hover).

Answer (score 2):

I made an example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/a5vuD/1/

You want to use classes instead of IDs to support multiple posts. Also, you should hide your "remove" elements on startup.